# Auto fill blank cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

I have downloaded sales data from webstore and the rows are itemised, but they only provide the date in one cell for the order.

I am trying to work out how I can auto fill the blank cells with the missing dates automatically?

I will then have the same data on another sheet so it would need to carry over for when the dates are filtered.

[image]

Comment: What should the values be? We can't invent the missing dates.

Comment: @Tomas I take it that the omissions are just repetitions of the above values like you would find in a pivot table.

Comment: Yes exactly they are to be repeated. Each row used represents a sold product item within the customer order but it only shows the date once. The issue I have is that order sizes (number of items) varies, so rather than define a specific cell, I need to try some thing like if the cell below is empty, enter the value from the above cell. Sorry i am still a novice so my explanations might not be the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like `=IF(A4="";B3;A4)` to take the above date if the left cell is empty. You will possibly have to use an auxiliary column for that.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang. I will give this a try. Thank you so much, I really appreciate you taking the time to help.